# Optimizing a High-Elf Warlock

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

I am rather new to 5e and I wanted to try out a Warlock so I chose High-Elf and wanted to know my best options that I could try. Any thoughts on creating the best High-Elf Warlock would be awesome. I am choosing the old one as a patron and path of the tome. I am most curious on spells and feats to take.

Comment: @David Still too broad; we need a better sense of what sort of character you expect this warlock to be. An emphasis, focus, or concept that can be used to *direct* suggestions for feats and spells, and that others can use as metrics to judge how well answers meet your criteria. The game is generally not designed for there to be a single "best" selection of feats and spells, even for a given race/class combination.

Comment: I would not have the fact that your character was a warlock in the past mechanically limit your character when porting into a new system. 5e's backgrounds can easily handle/explain your character's arcane past while letting you mechanically focus on being an arcane archer as a ranger.

Comment: @David, I think one of the ways that you can help to improve the question is to give us an idea of what sort of outcome you want to achieve, as opposed to having us do a bunch of research and listing some of the conclusions we have made.